# mysql cli indentation issue

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I've got some really weird output from an sql query:

```
mysql> select concat('abcdef', license_code, 'c') from fulfillment_licenses_list limit 1;
+-------------------------------------+
| concat('abcdef', license_code, 'c') |
+-------------------------------------+
c    |ef06F1-DFD2-4425-83AF-A4EF
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

As you can see, it is missing the first 4 characters (abcd), while the 'c' that should be concatenated to the end is somehow pushed to before the start of the line. What could cause this?

More importantly, what can I do about it? How do I query this table in a way that produces meaningful, usable output, without the weird indentation? If I include any other columns, the output gets even more messed up until it is totally unintelligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somehow managed to embed a carriage return (`\r`) into the data in your `license_code` field. You're going to need to clean up the data, and figure out what bug in the application introduced the carriage return.

Comment: Is there any way to query the table and make it ignore the return?

Comment: That's beyond my abilities in SQL. I suggest asking a new question on [so] or [dba.se].